# Efficient way to write to file in rest service

Tags: java, rest, thread-safety, java-io, filewriter

i have a java rest service that receives around 1000 requests per second. Each request has a payload of 1KB. I need to write this payload to a single file. Since there will be 1000 requests per second should i synchronize the writes to the file that uses FileWriter ? I also need to acknowledge the write to file succeeded for each request in response. This means i need to flush the write for each request.

If i synchronize the file writes the rest service performance will be degraded. Is there a way to write to file without synchronizing the file writes ?

Comment: It actually depends on the specifications of the server you have deployed your REST api to

Comment: Depends what you want to do, why you need to write to file, whether the payloads are **exactly** 1kB of not. You are absolutely not going to be able to process 1000 requests per second if you synchronize on a `FileWriter`. If you flush to disk on each write, I doubt you'll get 100 writes a second.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check how Log4J is logging information to text file? Its pretty even with millions of log msgs at a given time. You can refer to WriterAppender implementation for reference.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.log4j/com.springsource.org.apache.log4j/1.2.15/org/apache/log4j/WriterAppender.java#WriterAppender